# GEKKO returned non-optimal solution

Tags: python, mathematical-optimization, gekko

I want to use GEKKO to solve the following optimization problem:

```
Minimize x'Qx + 1e-10 * sum_{i=1}^n x_i^0.1
subject to 1' x = 1 and x >= 0
```

However, the following code returns `sol = [0., 0., 0. ,0. ,1.]` and `Objective: 1.99419` as a solution. Which is far from optimal, I'll explain why below.

```
import numpy as np
from gekko import GEKKO
n = 5
m = GEKKO(remote=False)
m.options.SOLVER = 1
m.options.IMODE = 3

x = [m.Var(lb=0, ub=1) for _ in range(n)]

m.Equation(m.sum(x) == 1)
np.random.seed(0)
Q = np.random.uniform(-1, 1, size=(n, n))
Q = np.dot(Q.T, Q)

## Add h_i^p
c, p = 1e-10, 0.1
for i in range(n):
    m.Obj(c * x[i] ** p)
    for j in range(n):
        m.Obj(x[i] * Q[i, j] * x[j])

m.solve(disp=True)
sol = np.array(x).flatten()
```

This is clearly wrong since if we only optimize the quadratic part (x'Qx) using below code, and put the solution to the initial objective, we get a much smaller objective value (`Objective: 0.02489503`). The `1e-10 * sum_{i=1}^n x_i^p` is esentially ignored since it is very small.

```
m1 = GEKKO(remote=False)
m1.options.SOLVER = 1
m1.options.OTOL = 1e-10
x1 = [m1.Var(lb=0, ub=1) for _ in range(n)]
m1.Equation(m1.sum(x1) == 1)
m1.qobj(b=np.zeros(n), A=2 * Q, x=x1, otype='min')
m1.solve(disp=True)
sol = np.array(x1).flatten()
```

**Is there any way to resolve this? Thank you!**

Comment: I think this is solved with a general-purpose NLP solver. There are really good QP solvers out there. It may be better to use QP solvers for QP problems.

Comment: Good observation! If the problem has over 1,000,000 variables then it may be better to switch over to a dedicated QP solver for solution speed. The IPOPT, BPOPT, and APOPT can handle larger problems but there is overhead with repeatedly calculating sparse gradients at every iteration. Here are additional examples (LPs) with Gekko and sparse matrices: https://apmonitor.com/pdc/index.php/Main/LinearProgramming

Comment: What happens if you first solve the convex QP (drop the `x^p` terms). Then add the `x^p` terms and use the QP solution as a starting point.

Comment: The reason for this is that the model is non-convex. So it is a good idea to get close by using the QP, and then use that as an initial point for the non-convex NLP.

Comment: The solvers use a Sequential Quadratic Programming approach so it should be a relatively similar result to just try the NLP solution. Each iteration is solving a QP to get a new search direction. There is additional information on the algorithms in the Optimization Course: https://apmonitor.com/me575/index.php/Main/QuasiNewton

Comment: No. Not the same. Sqp is not just dropping terms. It is building a different quadratic model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gekko solves nonlinear programming optimization problems with gradient-based methods: interior point and active set SQP. It looks like there is a problem with the objective function. Use matrix operations in Numpy to simplify the objective definition.

```py
## Create Objective
c, p = 1e-10, 0.1
obj = np.dot(np.dot(x,Q),x) + c*m.sum([xi**p for xi in x])
m.Minimize(obj)
```

Here is the modified script that solves with Gekko. Increase `MAX_ITER` if the default limit of `250` is reached.

```py
import numpy as np
from gekko import GEKKO
n = 5
m = GEKKO(remote=False)
m.options.SOLVER = 3
m.options.IMODE = 3

x = m.Array(m.Var,n,value=0.1, lb=1e-6, ub=1)

m.Equation(m.sum(x) == 1)

np.random.seed(0)
Q = np.random.uniform(-1, 1, size=(n, n))
Q = np.dot(Q.T, Q)
print(Q)

## Create Objective
c, p = 1e-10, 0.1
obj = np.dot(np.dot(x,Q),x) + c*m.sum([xi**p for xi in x])
m.Minimize(obj)

# adjust solver tolerance
m.options.RTOL=1e-10
m.options.OTOL=1e-10
m.options.MAX_ITER = 1000

m.solve(disp=True)
sol = np.array(x).flatten()
print('x: ', sol)
print('obj: ', m.options.OBJFCNVAL)
```

This gives an optimal solution that is also global because it is a Quadratic Programming (QP) problem (convex optimization). Using a nonlinear programming (SQP) solver for QP problems gives a solution with the IPOPT solver:

```
x:  [[0.36315827507] [0.081993130341] [1e-06] [0.086231281612] [0.46861632269]]
obj:  0.024895918696
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. But the objective I wanted is +c * m.sum (plus c, not minus). When I try changing to plus sign, it raises Solution Not Found. Is it because the objective function is not convex and hence theoretically unsolveable? Or is this a GEKKO specific problem? Sorry if this is a dumb question, I might be lacking the basics of mathematical optimization

Comment: When any of the `x` values become negative, the value of `x**0.1` produces an imaginary number. Try including a small lower bound constraint on `x` such as `lb=1e-6`. I submitted an edit with the correct sign on the extra term.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply John. It worked perfectly, thank you very much!!

Answer (score -2):

As far as I could see, `gekko` looks like it's built for machine learning, which focuses on local optimization opposed to global optimization, and typically most libraries will not be able to guarantee you optimal solutions.

If you really want optimal solutions, than for this case I would suggest looking into interval arithmetic. There are packages such as [mpmath](https://mpmath.org/doc/current/contexts.html#arbitrary-precision-interval-arithmetic-iv) which can offer this, though I have yet to see optimizers using it in my brief time searching.

The TL;DR on how interval arithmetic works is you feed in a range of inputs and get back a range of outputs. For example, you can test if `1` is in the range of possible outputs for `x1 + x2 + x3 + x4`, and you can see the minimum/maximum potential values for your objective function. In this way, you can progressively split your intervals in half, keeping only intervals for which your constraints are potentially satisfied and for which your objective function's maximum potential is at least the largest minimum potential. This allows you to achieve guaranteed convergence to global optimums at the cost of a lot more computation.